# Obtain the object of a list by multiple matching values ​in Java 8

Tags: java, performance

I'm trying to make a rule filtering by the highest value match.

I have a sale that contains several products and I have to apply a different rule to each product.

What is the best way to obtain this result?

```
List<Rule> rules = listOfRules();
String system = "MySystem1";

Map<Product, Rule> mapOfProductRule = new HashMap<Product, Rule>();

sale.getProducts().forEach(product -> {

    int points = 0;
    Rule matchedRule = null;

    for (Rule rule : rules) {

        if (system == rule.getSystem()) {
            int countMatchs = 0;
            if (sale.getValue1() == rule.getValue1()) countMatchs++;
            if (sale.getValue2() == rule.getValue2()) countMatchs++;
            if (product.getPvalue1() == rule.getPvalue1()) countMatchs++;
            if (product.getPvalue2() == rule.getPvalue2()) countMatchs++;

            if (countMatchs!= 0 && points < countMatchs)
            {
                points = countMatchs;
                matchedRule = rule;
            }
        }
    }

    mapOfProductRule.put(product, matchedRule);

});

return mapOfProductRule;
```

Comment: Hi Matheus, 
What does your points variable represent? You do no change it and then compare to countMatchs.

Comment: I forgot a part of the code, the points counter is to know what was the highest score so far

Comment: `match` is the same as `countMatchs`?

Comment: yes exactly ! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would move all the 4 if.. into a method in the `Rule` class

```
public int getScore(Sale sale, Product product) {
    int count = 0;
    if (this.getValue1() == sale.getValue1()) count++;
    //...
    return count;
}
```

Then I would replace the inner loop over `rules` with

```
Rule bestRule = rules.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(r -> r.getScore(sale, product)));
```

Comment: Thx, there is a better way to not write all the "if" count++ ?